# Problem getting the tags in a specific page using beatiful soup python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Im trying to get the info of each post from this page [www.toctoc.com](https://www.toctoc.com/search/index2/?dormitorios=0&banos=0&superficieDesde=0&superficieHasta=0&precioDesde=0&precioHasta=0&moneda=UF&tipoArriendo=true&tipoVentaUsado=false&tipoVentaNuevo=false&casaDepto=8&ordenarPorMoneda=UFCLP&ordenarDesc=false&ordernarPorFechaPublicacion=false&ordernarPorSuperficie=false&ordernarPorPrecio=false&pagina=1&esMobile=false&textoBusqueda=Regi%C3%B3n%20Metropolitana&textoOriginal=Regi%C3%B3n%20Metropolitana&tipoVista=lista&viewport=-71.715363%2C-34.29047%2C-69.769737%2C-32.922085&comuna=&region=Regi%C3%B3n%20Metropolitana%20de%20Santiago&atributos=&idle=true&zoom=7.053707424896949&buscando=true&vuelveBuscar=false&dibujaPoligono=true&resetMapa=true&animacion=false&idZonaHomogenea=0&esPrimeraBusqueda=false) with this code:

```
page = requests.get('website_url') #website url was too long
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

name_box = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'item'})
```

Output: []

Does anyone know how to find all code inside each class(each post)?

[Screenshot of website with inspection tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XueUj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has to run on the page. You could selenium with a wait for those elements to all be present. Then access specific elements. I just show top level for your class

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = 'https://www.toctoc.com/search/index2/?dormitorios=0&banos=0&superficieDesde=0&superficieHasta=0&precioDesde=0&precioHasta=0&moneda=UF&tipoArriendo=true&tipoVentaUsado=false&tipoVentaNuevo=false&casaDepto=8&ordenarPorMoneda=UFCLP&ordenarDesc=false&ordernarPorFechaPublicacion=false&ordernarPorSuperficie=false&ordernarPorPrecio=false&pagina=1&esMobile=false&textoBusqueda=Regi%C3%B3n%20Metropolitana&textoOriginal=Regi%C3%B3n%20Metropolitana&tipoVista=lista&viewport=-71.715363%2C-34.29047%2C-69.769737%2C-32.922085&comuna=&region=Regi%C3%B3n%20Metropolitana%20de%20Santiago&atributos=&idle=true&zoom=7.053707424896949&buscando=true&vuelveBuscar=false&dibujaPoligono=true&resetMapa=true&animacion=false&idZonaHomogenea=0&esPrimeraBusqueda=false'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
items = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item")))
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
#driver.quit()
```

Comment: thanks! Do you know how can I go to the next page to scrape all the pages at once? Im trying with `driver.find_element_by_class_name('page')` but button is not found.